# How do I print sum of elements that are corresponding to specific value?

Tags: c++

I have trouble dealing with this problem:
In first input line: int n - number of parcels delivered to the shop
Then in n lines: int a and int b - id of product and its quantity.
Desired output:
First line - x, number of unique products.
Then in x lines: int a and int b - id of product and its total quantity.
I.e.:

```
input
6
2 1
3 11
1 4
3 2
7 1
2 1

output
4
2 2
3 13
1 4
7 1
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
using namespace std;                                                            

int a_tab[1000000] = {0};                                                       
int b_tab[1000000] = {0};                                                       

int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);                                           
    cin.tie(NULL);                                                              

    unsigned int a;                                                             
    unsigned short b;                                                           

    unsigned int n;                                                             
    cin >> n;                                                                   

    unsigned int counter = n;                                                   

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                                                 
    {                                                                           
        cin >> a >> b;                                                          
        bool ax = false;                                                        
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)                                             
        {                                                                       
            if (a_tab[j] == a)                                                  
                {                                                               
                    b_tab[j] = b_tab[j] + b;                                    
                    ax = true;                                                  
                    counter--;                                                  
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
        }                                                                       
        if (ax == false)                                                        
        {                                                                       
            a_tab[i] = a;                                                       
            b_tab[i] = b;                                                       
        }                                                                       
        a = 0;                                                                  
        b = 0;                                                                  
    }                                                                           

        cout << counter << endl;                                                

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                                             
    {                                                                           
        if (a_tab[i] > 0)                                                       

        {                                                                       
            cout << a_tab[i] << " " << b_tab[i] << endl;                        
        }                                                                       

    }                                                                           



    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

But it seems, my algorithm is incorrect, because I'm running into Time Limit Exceeded error.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Looks like a good use case for a `std::map<int,int>`

Comment: @JeJo Why `std::set<std::pair<int, int>>`? If `first` is id and `second` is quantity, it wouldn't make sense to involve `second` into key for ordering. `std::unordered_map<int, int>` seems a reasonable alternative to me instead.

Comment: Thank you guys, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to cin to a set or unordered_map and cout of it. I'm not familiar with C++ so much, I usually use Python, but when I got TLE with C++ I haven't even thought about re-writing it in Python :D

Comment: Try to google [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). You should find numerous examples. E.g. it provides `operator[]` to use it like an array - an array which grows for each new key which was not yet in before. ([std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) has a very similar API but a different internal storage which has better average case performance by the cost of a worse worst case performance.) ;-)

Comment: As you mentioned Python: `std::map` is comparable with dictionary in Python.

Comment: Can you please provide the problem link so that the problem can be more clear because limit of 'a' and 'b' is not defined here.

Comment: Is it from a live challenge? Then this question should be closed because it is not allowed to discuss solutions during a live challenge. Otherwise share the problem link.

Comment: @shubhgkr This is not from live challenge, but the problem is also not in English, so the link would be useless

Comment: Can you please share the link so that solution can be optimized according to the input limits. @NotSoEasyAsUXpecteD

Answer (score 1):

I will show you the C++ solution for your question.

If this is some kind of competetive programming question (which I suspect, because of your statement "Time Limit Exceeded"), then you -maybe- need to forget this solution on try to learn "more-dirty" programming.

For your task, there is a more a less standard solution, and you will find at least 50 similar threads on SO, describing similar solutions.

You need to use a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, depending on your desired output. It seems that you do not require sorting, so `std::unordered_map`is the way to go.

Both of these containers have a subscript operator, which

- in case the element is already in the map, returns a reference to this element, or
- if the element is not in the map, it creates a new element, and then returns a reference to the new element

So, in any case, we get a reference to the element in the map. And we simply add the quantity to it. Thats all.

Then we output the result, using a range based for loop and structured bindings. This is also very simply and easy to read and understand.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>

// I do not want to type all the type 
// So, I do read from this stream and not from std::cin
// if you want to read from std::cin, then replace sourceData with std::cin in function main
std::istringstream sourceData{ R"(6
2 1
3 11
1 4
3 2
7 1
2 1)" };


int main() {

    // Define the result
    std::unordered_map<unsigned, unsigned> result{};

    // Get the number of lines to read
    if (size_t numberOfLines; sourceData >> numberOfLines) {

        // Read all lines as specified by the user
        for (size_t n = 0U; n < numberOfLines; ++n) {

            // Read id and count
            if (unsigned a{}, b{}; sourceData >> a >> b) {

                // some up grouped by id
                result[a] += b;
            }
        }
    }
    // Show the number of resulting lines
    std::cout << result.size() << "\n";

    // Show the result, so the id and the summed up quantity
    for (const auto& [id, totalQuantity] : result) {
        std::cout << id << " " << totalQuantity << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate Your help, but this soluton seems to be faulty. I get errors line 23 and 40

Comment: This has program has been checked and tested. It compiles, runs and produces the correct output. You need to enable C++17 features in your compiler. Please check.

Comment: Ah yes, now it works. However I forgot to write in the OP that answers should be given in the same order as they were inputed, i.e. if 2 1 was the first in-line 2 2 should be the first out-line. But I probably should sort that out myself instead of bothering You. ;)

Comment: Hm, I checked again 2 2 is the first output on my machine. I do not undestand . . .